# Service Worker Cache Sizes

Tags: browser, browser-cache, service-worker

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Service_Worker_API/Using_Service_Workers#Deleting_old_caches): "each browser has a hard limit on the amount of cache storage that a given service worker can use."

What are the current browser limits for Service Worker Cache?

- Firefox
- Chrome
- Opera

Answer (score 1):

Here's the documentation about the storage limit in Firefox: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API/Browser_storage_limits_and_eviction_criteria#Storage_limits.